# Make parent div height dynamic which choose child div?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 div inside parent div like this

```
<div class='parent'>
    <div class='title'></div>
    <div class='content'></div>
</div>
```

Now I want to make it like this image shown:- 
[image]

content class is nested in Parent div.
How to make parent div height dynamic so that  it will choose one child div bigger.
I have tried to make it. but my parent div choose one child div to smaller

Comment: define style  `.parent {hidden: overflow;}`

Comment: you mean .parent {overflow: hidden;}
i have to use like this. but not working.
If i use that, content div got slice  by parent div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as my understanding of your question, you need you parent div to have height adjust according to your content div.

You just have to add an extra div with class clearfix in the end of your parent div.

Below is the snippet you can use for your problem's solution:

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;}
.title, .content, .parent{
padding:10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.clearfix, .clearfix:before, .clearfix:after{
  clear:both;
}
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after{
  content:"";
}
.title{
  float:left;
  height:100px;
  width:30%;
}
.content{
  float:left;
  height:200px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: calc(70% - 10px); 
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
    <div class='title'></div>
    <div class='content'></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is helpful.

Comment: Glad to be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally there is a solution with `display:inline-block`.
The parent element gets the`display:inline-block;`, the title `float:left;` and the content `float:right;`.

Inserting percentages as width and padding makes the thing responsive.

```css
.parent {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3%;
}
.content {
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: right;
  width: 63%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.title {
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30%;
  height: 60px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='title'>title</div>
  <div class='content'>content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content</div>
</div>
```